# Log cmd output of batch file ran by task scheduler and save with date/time in filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, cmd

I have a task in windows scheduler that runs a batch file every minute. This batch file svn updates a number of folders then runs a perl script that forks off onto a number of other scripts.

Is there a command to enter in the batch file that will ensure all cmd output from running the task will be logged into a file with the date/time as the filename?
e.g. if the program runs at 12:00 1st Jan 2014 it will be saved like: 1200-1-1-2014.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the batch file, you can add something like:

```
setlocal
@For /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @(
    Set Month=%%A
    Set Day=%%B
    Set Year=%%C
)
set Date=%Day%_%Month%_%Year%

perl [script name] >> [path to log]/%Date%.log

endlocal
```

I'm not sure about the syntax for the 'time' part of it but that should get you started on the right path.

Edit: found more info about getting the 'time' in this post:

[How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

Answer (score 0):

Not as such, but using one of the [excellent logging modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Logger) on CPAN you could write a short filer that echoes its input via a logger, and get the time stamps done for you.

Otherwise, you'll need to be using something like [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html) to control all of your output collection, and then use the logger in your main program.

Does windows even do pipes?